# Using two values in css at once

Tags: css

Okay so the main part of my website on the main page needs to be -5px what it currently is,
currently I am using

```
margin-left: auto;
```

to align it, but I need it to be -5px too, and this wont work:

```
margin-left: auto -5px;
```

wont work, how do I accomplish what I wish to achieve here?
What I mean is: it needs to be auto minus 5px so it is what it normally is with auto but 5px backwards, if that makes sense.

Comment: I wonder if `margin-left: calc(auto - 5px);` would work...? **edit**, nope, **[doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/QEVq7/)**

Comment: You can't auto and move it 5 left on the same element. You either need to contain the element in another element and switch your CSS, or fix the alignment on your site.

Comment: Have you considered putting this main part inside a bounding `div` that is offset by `5px`?

Comment: Please post your existing HTML structure as well as any other CSS you have on the element.

Answer (score 3):

```
#div {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I stand corrected, it looks like it can be done. But he would want `left: -5px;`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is some additional context missing, but it seems like this would be the same as adding `5px` margin to the right:

http://jsfiddle.net/QEVq7/1/

```
div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The "auto" will automatically adjust to the change in right margin and shift the element 5px to the left.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do 'auto - 5px' with CSS sadly

If you're aiming at going pure CSS you have two options IMO:
Depending on the context you can use an 'absolute' or 'relative' positioning and enter the value of right or left OR you could manually enter the margin-left pixel count.
Or else you have two choices; you can calculate and change it in JS which is far from ideal since it's on your main page and is messy. If that fails you can use a language that compiles into CSS such as CoffeeScript (http://coffeescript.org/)

Good Luck!